# How to remove all <div> images with a given url in jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove all background images inside unnamed unclassified `<div>`s from a webpage using javascript by its url?

The actual html tag for these images is the following:

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:150px;height:150px;top:0px;
background:url(img-150x150.png) no-repeat left top;"></div>
```

What I am trying is the following:

```
$('*').filter(function () {
    return $(this).css('background-image') == 'url("img150x150.png")'
}).remove();
```

But this is not working.

Comment: You could go through all `<div>`s and check their `.style.backgroundImage`. Probably quite slow though.

Comment: please explain more as it is not very clear what you are trying to do ,, how many images u have and are u using jQuery?

Comment: @shireefkhatab: number of images in unknown at program time.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can check if `img-150x150.png` exists in `background-image` string, because it contains url with absolute path to image..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //this is if you want to remove those divs
  $('body>div').filter(function() {

    return $(this).css("background-image").indexOf("img-150x150.png") != -1
  }).remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div style="width:150px;height:150px;top:0px;
background:url('img-150x150.png') no-repeat left top;"></div>

<div style="width:150px;height:150px;top:0px;
background:url('img-150x150.png') no-repeat left top;"></div>

<div style="width:150px;height:150px;top:0px;
background:url('img-150x150.png') no-repeat left top;"></div>

<div style="background:yellow;width:150px;height:150px;top:0px;"></div>
  </body>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //this is if you want to change background color of  those divs
  $('body>div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("background-image").indexOf("img-150x150.png") != -1
  }).each(function(){$(this).css("background","red");})
});
```

```css
div{
margin:10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div style="width:50px;height:50px;top:0px;
    background:url('img-150x150.png') no-repeat left top;"></div>

    <div style="width:50px;height:50px;top:0px;
    background:url('img-150x150.png') no-repeat left top;"></div>

    <div style="width:50px;height:50px;top:0px;
    background:url('img-150x150.png') no-repeat left top;"></div>

    <div style="background:yellow;width:50px;height:50px;top:0px;"></div>
  
  </body>
```

And since `indexOf` is not supported in IE 7,8 here is a polyfill:

```
Array.prototype.indexOf || (Array.prototype.indexOf = function(d, e) {
    var a;
    if (null == this) throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
    var c = Object(this),
        b = c.length >>> 0;
    if (0 === b) return -1;
    a = +e || 0;
    Infinity === Math.abs(a) && (a = 0);
    if (a >= b) return -1;
    for (a = Math.max(0 <= a ? a : b - Math.abs(a), 0); a < b;) {
        if (a in c && c[a] === d) return a;
        a++
    }
    return -1
});
```

Comment: Allthough it is nice to have a polyfill in case somebody uses IE7, 8. But they are no longer supported by Microsoft. And it isn't necessary to have polyfills.

Comment: @ThomasJunk Well I think it's better to support something if it doesn't require a lot of effort. But I only posted it as nice to have

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/wr650mjg/)

```js
// loop through all divs
$('div').each(function() {
  // store the value of the style attribute in a variable
  var divStyle = $(this).attr('style');
  // remove the background part
  divStyle = divStyle.replace('background:url(img-150x150.png) no-repeat left top;', '');
  //inject the new and modified style attribute back
  $(this).attr('style', divStyle);
});
```

```css
div{ width:70px; height:50px; display:inline-block; border:1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:absolute;width:150px;height:150px;top:0px;
background:url(img-150x150.png) no-repeat left top;"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;width:150px;height:150px;top:0px;
background:url(img-150x150.png) no-repeat left top;"></div>
```

Now the `style` attribute of each of these divs is:

```
style="position:absolute;width:150px;height:150px;top:0px;"
```